# Event count discrepancy between Firebase Analytics, Facebook, Appsflyer. (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, facebook, firebase-analytics, appsflyer

I have a Flutter project that integrates three marketing event registration services: [Firebase Analytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics), [Facebook App Events](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events), and [Appsflyer](https://pub.dev/packages/appsflyer_sdk). During testing, all services successfully register the events, and the counts are consistent. However, in the production environment, I am experiencing a significant gap between the event counts reported by these services.

For instance, let's take the event "**registration_completed**" as an example. When I checked the count for this event two days ago, Firebase Analytics reported 100 events, Facebook Event Manager reported 35 events, and Appsflyer reported only 11 events. It's worth noting that I'm not passing any additional parameters for this particular event.

I'm puzzled as to why such a large discrepancy exists between the event counts across these services. I've ensured that the code for event registration is correctly implemented, and the testing results indicate that it is functioning as expected. However, in the production environment, the numbers seem to diverge significantly.

Could you please help me understand the possible reasons behind this inconsistency? Is there anything specific I should investigate or any additional configuration that needs to be done to ensure accurate event tracking across all three services in a production environment?

Thank you for your assistance!

A simplified part of my code:

```dart
  final _facebook = FacebookAppEvents();
  final _firebase = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;

  final _appsflyer = AppsflyerSdk(
    AppsFlyerOptions(
      afDevKey: afDevKey,
      appId: appId,
      showDebug: kDebugMode,
      timeToWaitForATTUserAuthorization: 50, // for iOS 14
    ),
  );

  void init() {
    _appsflyer.initSdk();
  }

  logEvent(String name, Map values) async {
    await Future.wait([
      _appsflyer.logEvent(name, values),
      _facebook.logEvent(name: name, parameters: values),
      _firebase.logEvent(name: name, parameters: firebaseValues)
    ]);
  }
```

Comment: Different users might simply have different tracking services _blocked_ on their devices ...?

Comment: It is possible for Facebook because it requires installed Facebook services with an active account. However, it seems like there is no requirement difference between the Appsflyer and Firebase Analytics services.
Blocked services may cause a 10-20% gap, I think, not 90% :(